# Как себя ведет стек в случае обработки исключения?

Tags: java

Допустим вызывается метод в котором есть код, обрабатывающий исключение. Есть ли гарантия, что метод, вызвавший его получит упрввление от него **когда он выполнится**? Стоит ли добавлять

```
finally{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Уточните суть вопроса. Почему вы выделили - "когда он выполнится", т.е. завершится нормально?

Comment: @Oxdb, закончит выполнение

Comment: Привидите пример кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял что имеется в виду. Гарантируется ли выполнение блока finally? да, jvm гарантирует выполнение этого блока, за исключением случаев когда программа впринципе не может выполняться(например, код

```
public void func(){ 
    try{ func() } 
    finally { func() } 
}
```

заставит комп зависнуть, т.к. jvm будет отчаянно пытаться выполнить все блоки finally)
Если вы спрашиваете продолжит ли работу такой код после вызова fucnA() - да, конечно, продолжит

```
private static void funcA() {
    try {...}
    catch (Exception e) {...}
}
public static void main(String... args) {
    funcA();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Второй `если` - то, что я хотел узнать. Но у меня сомнения, что после вызова метода `funcA` код выполнится именно тогда, когда тот закончит выполнение, тоесть вот вызвался и дальше поехало.

Comment: нет, программа продолжит работу только если этот метод вызывать в отдельном потоке, т.е., что-то вроде `new Thread(() -> {funcA()}).start()`